# Why treeAggregate always change the partition to 70?

Tags: apache-spark, logistic-regression

Background:
I have several billion rows, which I need to use to run logistic regression. I choose L-BFGS and it succeed when faced to a small data set(1 hundred million), but always failed when faced to the several billion rows.

I read the log and I find this error:

```
Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 54 in stage 37.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: 
    Lost task 54.3 in stage 37.0 (TID 79670, 10.215.155.83):
        java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Requested array size exceeds VM limit
```

Which is triggered by:

```
treeAggregate at StandardScaler.scala:55
```

And I find the function `treeAggregate` seems change the partition number to 70, which I set to 5000. It explains the OOM, but I don't know why, and I wonder how to change it to 5000 to avoid OOM(VM's memory limit is 14G which cannot be changed).

Comment: Have you set `spark.default.parallelism`?

Comment: @zero323 sure, I set it to 5000.

Comment: Have you tried to repartition the rdd or dataframe before fit lr?

Comment: did you fix it? i met this situation too